# Why are Random Forests splitted based on m random features?

Tags: random-forest, ensemble-learning

I was watching the following tutorial on [Random forests](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7iDkcpOr_g&t=531) and it says that, 
"at each node, choose random subset of m features and only consider splitting on those features"
I do not understand why we choose m features. Why don't we consider all features?

e.g. Where the features are height, weight, age and m was 2, the random subspace could be height and weight? How does this work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as fitting each tree in the forest with a random subset sample (a bootstrap sample) of the available data adds stochasticity to improve the out-of-sample fit (by reducing the variance component of the error), so does selecting $m$ variables within which to search for each fit add stochasticity. The extra stochasticity makes each tree a poorer model than it would be without the random selection of variables and this is how the Random Forest achieves lower error over a single tree or bagging, which is Random Forests without the random selection of $m$ variables.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, an earlier paper (predating the "random forest" terminology) from Leo Breiman considered all features as you suggest [[Breiman 1996]](http://www.machine-learning.martinsewell.com/ensembles/bagging/Breiman1996.pdf). Below are some relevant excerpts from this article. First, some notation:

> A learning set of $\mathcal{L}$ consists of data $\left\{ (y_n,x_n),n=1,...,N\right\}$ where the $y$'s are either class labels or a numerical response. Assume we have a procedure for using this learning set to form a predictor $\varphi(\textbf{x},\mathcal{L})$ -- if the input is $\textbf{x}$ we predict $y$ by $\varphi(\textbf{x},\mathcal{L})$

The idea behind bagging (and, by extension, random forests) is to stochastically construct many different predictors $\varphi$ and aggregate this population predictors into a single predictor, denoted $\varphi_B$, which generally has superior performance to any of the individual predictors. Stochasticity is added by constructing each predictor on a bootstrap sample of the original training set, rather than the entirety of $\mathcal{L}$. As Gavin Simpson mentioned, selecting a random subset of features adds even more stochasticity to the construction of individual predictors. Breiman (1996) writes:

> A critical factor in whether bagging will improve accuracy is the stability of the procedure for constructing $\varphi$. If changes in $\mathcal{L}$, i.e. a [bootstrap] replicate of $\mathcal{L}$, produces small changes in $\varphi$, then $\varphi_B$ will be close to $\varphi$. **Improvement will occur for unstable procedures where a small change in $\mathcal{L}$ can result in large changes in $\varphi$** . . . The evidence, both experimental and theoretical, is that bagging can push a good but unstable procedures a significant step towards optimality. On the other hand, it can slightly degrade the performance of stable procedures. *[Emphasis Added]*

The paper then goes on to provide said theoretical and experimental evidence. Breiman's seminal description of random forests [(Breiman, 1999)](http://machinelearning202.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/60606349/breiman_randomforests.pdf) credits Tim Kam Ho for developing "the random subspace method" which adds additional instability by selecting $m$ random features to grow each tree (rather than each node). The original publication [(Ho, 1998)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/709601) appears to be behind a paywall unfortunately.

One final note -- one interesting question is what to choose for $m$? That is, how many random features should we select to split on for each node? There is a section in Breiman (1999) devoted to this question. The basic conclusion is that the choice does not matter substantially, as long as $m$ is relatively small compared to the total number of features.